# How to get panel transparency in Xfce version 4.14 and newer

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, panel

My experience is this: Linux Mint Xfce 19.3 came with a Xfce panel version (4.14.1) in which transparency cannot be set anymore. The same in Mint 20 (also  Xfce 4.14).

In previous versions (e.g. in Xfce 4.12 from Mint Xfce 19.2) that used to be done through an "alpha option" slider:

[image]

That slider is absent in later Xfce versions like 4.14:

[image]

---

This would be normal if compositing were disabled, but it's not (can change windows opacity). It could be a new feature or a new bug.

Is there a way of getting a transparent Xfce panel in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Xfce 4.14 Documentation's [How to create a fully/partially transparent panel](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/preferences/transparent-panel):

1. In the "Appearance" tab in the Panel Settings, select the “Solid
   color” style and click the Color button.

[image]

2. Click on the `+` button under "Custom" to create a new color in
   the color picker.

[image]

3. Adjust the slider at the bottom of the color picker from fully
   opaque (right) to fully transparent (left), according to the desired
   result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this comment](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3834#comment-152970) (on blog.linuxmint.com - under [this one](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3834#comment-152694), which confirms my experience):

[image]

Opening Gimp, "File" - "New", with 50x50 size and, in advanced options, set "Fill with: Transparency" .

[image]

Press OK and "File" - "Export as" - select PNG.

In Xfce panel preferences for appearance select that as background image.

If you don't have GIMP you can have the transparent image:

[image]

You don't see it because it's transparent. It's [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGFgU.png).